# MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended. findOne() function inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I have a set of students with a single key, I wanted to get the details of each one by one. The error that I'm facing is: MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

```
async function getChildrenDetails(client, instituteDatabase, childrenList) {
  let childrenListWithDetails = [];
  Object.keys(childrenList).forEach(async (child) => {
    const childClassAndRollNo = childrenList[child];

    const childWithDetails = await client
      .db(instituteDatabase)
      .collection("student")
      .findOne({ class: childClassAndRollNo.class }, { roll_no: childClassAndRollNo.roll_no });
    childrenListWithDetails.push = childWithDetails;
  });
  return childrenListWithDetails;
}
```

```
        let childrenListWithDetails = await getChildrenDetails(client, institute.institute_database, parent.children);
```

I think the findOne() is not waiting for the respone to come, before the connection closes.

Comment: can you share your client init code like and its closing?
`const client = await MongoClient.connect(.....);`
`client.close();`

Comment: `const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    try {
    await client.connect(); ...................
   .................... finally {
    await client. Close();
  }`

Comment: Ok, i think the finnally code block if closing the client connection before you hit the api for data, can you try something like that
init the client inside the fucntion

`async function getChildrenDetails( instituteDatabase, childrenList) {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(.....);
   let childrenListWithDetails = [];
     ....
     childrenListWithDetails.push(childWithDetails);
   });
   return childrenListWithDetails;
    client.close()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}`

Comment: I tried to remove the function and write the code in place, It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the return childrenListWithDetails; statement is not waiting for the asynchronous operations to complete before returning. Since the findOne function is asynchronous, using it within a forEach loop may lead to incorrect behavior, and the loop might not wait for the asynchronous operations to complete before moving on to the next iteration. As far as i know, forEach method only accepts a synchronous function, and therefore is NOT compatible with the async/await syntax. This could potentially be causing the MongoDB session to be closed prematurely. Give this alternative approach a try,

```js
async function getChildrenDetails(client, instituteDatabase, childrenList) {
  const promises = Object.keys(childrenList).map(async (child) => {
    const childClassAndRollNo = childrenList[child];

    const childWithDetails = await client
      .db(instituteDatabase)
      .collection("student")
      .findOne({ class: childClassAndRollNo.class, roll_no: childClassAndRollNo.roll_no });

    return childWithDetails;
  });

  const childrenListWithDetails = await Promise.all(promises);

  return childrenListWithDetails;
}
```